# How to adjust the plot height in Shiny App

Tags: r, plot, shiny, height

It's my first time developing a Shiny App.

I want to make the height of the plot adjustable to the screen size, but nothing I've tried worked.

[image: The plot looks like this now]

As you can see at the picture there's a blank space under the plot, so I want to fix that by making plot's height adjustable.

Here's the code. It is **not reproducable**, because I'm creating a model with local files.

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("yeti"),
       navbarPage(
       "Анализ тональности",
       tabPanel("Облако слов"),
       tabPanel("Проверка предложения"), 
       tabPanel("SVM-модель",
                mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"), width = "100%", height = "1100px")),
       )#navbarPage
) #fluidPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    beta.svm <- drop(t(model$coefs) %*% dfmat_train[model$index,])
    plot(colSums(dfmat_train),
         beta.svm,
         pch = 19,
         col = rgb(0,0,0,.3),
         cex =.5, 
         log = "x", 
         main = "Коэффициенты SVM-модели",
         ylab = "<--- Негативные комм. --- Позитивные комм.--->", 
         xlab = "Общее количество появлений", 
         xlim = c(1,500))
    text(colSums(dfmat_train),beta.svm, colnames(dfmat_train), pos = 4, cex = .9)
  })
}


####################################
# Create the shiny app             #
####################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I've already tried is changing `height` parameters in `plot()` and in `plotOutput()`. It didn't help.
So, the question is: how do I make the plot height adjustable or at least larger?